# Using LD_PRELOAD in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I want to install tensorflow library in my system(Linux 2.6.32_1-18-0-0 x86_64 GNU/Linux), however, since libc in my system is too old, some function definitions cannot be found. Error message is shown as follows:

```
$ python
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/root/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/root/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/root/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /root/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: symbol memcpy, version GLIBC_2.14 not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

So I implement the missing functions myself, and compiled it as a so, put it in /home/tensorflow/mylibc/mylibc.so

And when starting python next time, I do it like this

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/home/tensorflow/mylibc/mylibc.so python
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>>>
```

Everything seems ok and is actually ok in my more tests.

However, when running jupyter (ipython notebook), in the notebook, when I type "import tensorflow", I got the import error again
I run jupyter as follows:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/home/tensorflow/mylibc/mylibc.so  jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

and the error is like follows

```
ImportError: /root/.jumbo/opt/gcc46/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /root/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

Then, I decide to write a shell script to "wrapper" python. just like the follows:

```
$ cd ~/.jumbo/bin # the python binary directory
$ ls -l | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      234 Oct 10 03:58 ipython
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      234 Oct 10 03:58 ipython2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       87 Oct 10 05:40 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14 Aug 15 02:42 python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        9 Aug 15 02:42 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Aug 15 02:42 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     9864 Jul 26 03:17 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1626 Jul 26 03:17 python2.7-config
$ rm python
$ vim python # I typed the following text into file python, making python as a wrapper for python2.7, the actual executable file
#!/bin/sh
LD_PRELOAD=/home/tensorflow/mylibc/mylibc.so "/root/.jumbo/bin/python2.7" $@

$ chmod +x python
```

Then I ran jupyter again, starting a new notebook, trying to import tensorflow. however got the same importing error again.

I listed the process of jupyter and found when starting a new notebook, jupyter will actually spawn a separate process. It is python2.7 instead of python, to execute the new notebook

```
root       792  0.1  0.0 685252 43856 ?        Ssl  06:31   0:00 /root/.jumbo/bin/python2.7 -m ipykernel -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-d8e49d7b-d36f-4806-8013-be5a7c3a2028.json
root      1020  0.5  0.0  13352  1348 ?        S    06:58   0:00 /bin/sh /root/.jumbo/bin/python /root/.jumbo/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

So, my question is, how to make LD_PRELOAD actually work in my jupyter notebook? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: you can modify notebook environment using `os.environ` from inside the notebook

Comment: I've tried, both in jupyter's config file(by setting --config = path-to-config-file) and in the notebook itself, but still seems not work

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is edit the Jupyter Notebook environment variables manually

Where these are stored depends on the setup you're using

- if they are available system wide, you should be able to find them via `jupyter kernelspec list`, which for me points to `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels`.
- if you're using a python venv they are instead inside the env folder, similarly in `ENV/share/jupyter/kernels`.

Here you can copy one of the folders to create a new kernel, or just edit the existing kernels.
The `kernel.json` file defines the properties of the specific kernel, so to add LD_PRELOAD you need to add

```json
"env":{
  "LD_PRELOAD":"YOUR/PRELOAD/FOLDER.so"
 }
```

More properties of the kernel can be altered, according to [the documentation](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernel-specs)

I learned this after getting a similar issue, wanting it to work even inside VSCode instead of using a weird script to invoke the Jupyter.
I found the solution by asking [phind.com](https://www.phind.com). I am not affiliated, but i wanted to share how i found this out.